# Bucket Customers based on Points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a customer table. I am trying to filter each ParentCustomerID based on multiple points they have and select a row based on the below conditions:

- IF 0 points & negative points, select the row with the highest negative point (i.e. -30 > -20)
- IF 0 points & positive points, select the row with the highest positive point
- IF Positive & Negative Points, select the row with the highest positive point
- IF Positive, 0 points, and Negative points, select the row with the highest positive point
- IF 0 Points mark, select any row with 0 points
- IF All Negative, select the row with the highest negative point (i.e. -30 > -20)

1:M relationship between ParentCustomerID and ChildCustomerID

| ParentCustomerID | ChildCustomerID | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 101 | 2 | -20.0 |
| 101 | 3 | -30.50 |
| 102 | 4 | 20.86 |
| 102 | 5 | 0.0 |
| 102 | 6 | 50.0 |
| 103 | 7 | 10.0 |
| 103 | 8 | 50.0 |
| 103 | 9 | -30.0 |
| 104 | 10 | -30.0 |
| 104 | 11 | 0.0 |
| 104 | 12 | 60.80 |
| 104 | 13 | 40.0 |
| 105 | 14 | 0.0 |
| 105 | 15 | 0.0 |
| 105 | 16 | 0.0 |
| 106 | 17 | -20.0 |
| 106 | 18 | -30.80 |
| 106 | 19 | -40.20 |

Output should be:

| ParentCustomerID | ChildCustomerID | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 3 | -30.50 |
| 102 | 6 | 50.0 |
| 103 | 8 | 50.0 |
| 104 | 12 | 60.80 |
| 105 | 16 | 0.0 |
| 106 | 19 | -40.20 |

Note: for the rows customer 105, any row can be chosen because they all have 0 points.

Note2: Points can be float and ChildCustomerID can be missing (np.nan)

I do not know how to group each ParentCustomerID, check the above conditions, and select a specific row for each ParentCustomerID.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What if all the values are negative in a group?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Then we need to choose the max negative point (i.e. -30 > -20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

```
df['abs'] = df['Points'].abs()
df['pri'] = np.sign(df['Points']).replace(0, -2)

(
    df.sort_values(['pri', 'abs'])
      .drop_duplicates('ParentCustomerID', keep='last')
      .drop(['pri', 'abs'], axis=1)
      .sort_index()
)
```

### How this works

- Assign a temporary column named `abs` with the absolute values of `Points`
- Assign a temporary column named `pri`(priority) corresponding to arithmetic signs(i.e, -1, 0, 1) of values in `Points`, Important hack: replace `0` with `-2` so that zero always has least priority.
- Sort the values by priority and absolute values
- Drop the duplicates in sorted dataframe keeping the last row per `ParentCustomerID`

#### Result

```
    ParentCustomerID  ChildCustomerID  Points
2                101                3   -30.5
5                102                6    50.0
7                103                8    50.0
11               104               12    60.8
15               105               16     0.0
18               106               19   -40.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [101,   1,  0.0],
    [101,   2,  -20.0],
    [101,   3,  -30.50],
    [102,   4,  20.86],
    [102,   5,  0.0],
    [102,   6,  50.0],
    [103,   7,  10.0],
    [103,   8,  50.0],
    [103,   9,  -30.0],
    [104,   10,     -30.0],
    [104,   11,     0.0],
    [104,   12,     60.80],
    [104,   13,     40.0],
    [105,   14,     0.0],
    [105,   15,     0.0],
    [105,   16,     0.0],
    [106,   17,     -20.0],
    [106,   18,     -30.80],
    [106,   19,     -40.20]
],columns=['ParentCustomerID',  'ChildCustomerID',  'Points'])

data = df.groupby('ParentCustomerID').agg({
  'Points': [lambda x: np.argmax(x) if (np.array(x) > 0).sum() else np.argmin(x), list],
  'ChildCustomerID': list
})

pd.DataFrame(data.apply(lambda x: (x["ChildCustomerID", "list"][x["Points", "<lambda_0>"]], x["Points", "list"][x["Points", "<lambda_0>"]]), axis=1).tolist(), index=data.index).rename(columns={
    0: "ChildCustomerID",
    1: "Points"
}).reset_index()
```

Comment: I am getting a Type Error for the second piece (pd.DataFrame). "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float"

Comment: Points can be float - maybe that's the reason that is giving Type Error?

Comment: @EZ72 No, I used the above code and it worked... are there any differences?

Comment: I just ran the sample you provided, and I am still getting the same error. I tried to update my pandas and NumPy libraries. No luck, still getting the same error. I am running this on Jupyter Notebook if matters.